# Why are there thick edges in Voronoi 3D/4D?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural, mathematics

I was playing with Voronoi and discovered that if I use 3D/4D, some of the edges are thicker than others. In my opinion, it looks unnatural and neither *colorramp* nor *greater/less than* can solve this problem. There's no such problem with 2D Voronoi but it also doesn't have W input so I can't properly animate the texture. And as you can see on the 1st screenshot even if I'm using a plane with *Z coordinate equals to 0* or *UV coordinates* (I believe both give me 2D) this problem is still actual.

Could someone explain why does this happen and how do I get rid of these?

[image: Voronoi 3D/4D has a lot of edges which are thicker than they should be]

[image: Voronoi 2D has no thick edges]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a 3D or 4D texture you are mapping a cross-section of a pattern that occurs throughout 3D space to the surface of your object.

[image: Voronoi represented in 3d space]

So sometimes you're cutting through an area that is centered above or below your cross-sectional plane and it creates a different gradient.

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much sense! Never thought about it like that :)

Comment: But how can I make all edges the same thickness? I tried to multiply Z component by 0 and by 1000 (to make cells very small of Z) but this doesn't solve this. Is it even possible? Any ideas?
I could unwrap the mesh I want to have this texture and use 2D but W input is very useful for me.

Comment: It's a good question, it would have been useful for me on my stained glass project but I couldn't figure out any way in the evening I had to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Tighten up the white color stop and it should clamp down some of that greyscale. Or try constant instead of linear as well.

Comment: This will affect all of the edges equally but some of them will still remain thicker than others. I just don't understand why does this happen.